# Excel 2013 VBA - fill a range of cells with data from another worksheet related to a certain key

Tags: excel, vba

my problem described best with an example.

I got a worksheet like the following

[image]

I want to fill the empty cells at the bottom automatically like a drill down feature based on the data in another worksheet which looks like the following

[image]

The key value to the data from the second worksheet is the project code. So we have to loop over the data in the second sheet, fetch row by row and insert into first worksheet starting in row 5 just beneath "Task Code".

Unfortunately I found no solutions anywhere or my search was not exact enough and the topmost answers did not match my needs.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you can use this VBA code below and assign the macro to a button:

[First Worksheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LW8g.png)

[Second worksheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwUfC.png)

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A5:C5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim searchValue As Integer
searchValue = Cells(2, 1).Value

Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=searchValue
Range("B2:D2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$7").AutoFilter Field:=1
Range("A10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("A11").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
```